# R loop using a vector with 11 mini data sets

Tags: r, loops, vector

I'm trying to create a loop to run a function, rpt, on 11 different data sets. Here is the code

```
 for (i in data_names) {
    foo = rpt(odba ~ (1|date.1), grname = "date.1", data= data_names[i], datatype = "Gaussian", 
                        nboot = 500, npermut = 0)
    print(foo)
  }
```

The data_names is the vector with the datasets as shown. Each data set has a column for Turtle, date.1, and odba (the y-variable in this case).

```
data_names = c(R3L12rep, R3L1rep, R3L2rep, R3L4rep, R8L1rep, R3L9rep, R3L8rep, 
                R3L11rep, R8NATL123rep, R8L4rep, R4L8rep)
```

When I run the loop it tells me

> Error in stats::complete.cases(data[all.vars(formula)]) :
> invalid 'type' (unknown) of argument

I'm not sure as to why it is doing this. I've tried putting quotations around the data sets in the vector but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Put the data in a `list`: `data_names = list(R3L12rep, R3L1rep, ...)`. Then iterate over the indices, `for (i in 1:length(data_names))`, and since it's a list us `[[` to index it, `data = data_names[[i]]`. You probably want to put the results in a `list` too, otherwise `foo` will be overwritten each iteration. Before the loop initialize `foo = list()`, and in the loop `foo[[i]] = rpt(...)`.

Comment: @GregorThomas it seems like that worked for the first 6 data sets thank you. I got some errors though like **boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular** and **Error in lme4::lFormula(formula = formula, data = data, control = list( : 
  0 (non-NA) cases**.

Comment: So there are issues with some of your data sets--sounds like a lot of missing values. You can look at the value of `i` to see the iteration it stopped at, and investigate `data_names[[i]]` deeper. Or see the [R for Data Science book's](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#dealing-with-failure) chapter on iteration, section on Failure to modify your function by telling it what to do if it gets an error.

Comment: take a look at `?stats::complete.cases`, (the test your data is currently failing) then subset the data you're sending so you are only presenting complete cases.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Thomas, I had some naming issues with the data set. All good now.